# How to trigger the ttk.ComboboxSelected event

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm just wondering if it is possible to trigger the  `ComboboxSelected` virtual event when using the set method of `Combobox`, just as the comment of the following code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

master = tk.Tk()

country = ttk.Combobox(master)
country['values'] = ('USA', 'Canada', 'Australia')
country.pack()

# set a default value, but it seems the value is not selected
country.set(country['values'][1])

master.mainloop()
```

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

master = tk.Tk()


def select_combobox(event):

    to = int(gradations.get())
    print(to)

    for entry in entry_list[:to]:
        entry.config(state="normal")
    for entry in entry_list[to:]:
        entry.config(state="disable")


gradations = ttk.Combobox(master)
gradations['values'] = ('1', '2', '3')
gradations.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", select_combobox)
gradations.pack()

entry_list = []
entry1 = tk.Entry(master)
entry1.pack()
entry_list.append(entry1)
entry2 = tk.Entry(master)
entry2.pack()
entry_list.append(entry2)
entry3 = tk.Entry(master)
entry3.pack()
entry_list.append(entry3)

# gradations.set(1)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can create a custom class inherited from `Combobox` and override the `set()` and `current()` functions.  Then you can trigger the virtual event using `.event_generate('<<ComboboxSelected>>')` inside the override functions.

Comment: i have just pasted the new code, the selected value of Combobox control the state of entry. However,  If the value of Combobox is assigned with set method (as the comment part did), it seems the ComboboxSelected event can not be triggered

Comment: For your case, you can simply call `gradations.event_generate('<<ComboboxSelected>>')` or `select_combobox(None)` after calling `gradations.set(...)`.

Comment: it really works   @acw1668